# doing comparison if else in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, ternary-operator

I want to do a comparison such as:

```
if <field> == 0 then "-"
```

Can somebody tell me the syntax using JasperReports?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

iReport (JasperReports) uses a [Ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). For example, consider the following logic:

```
IF boolean condition THEN
  execute true code
ELSE
  execute false code
END IF
```

Using a ternary operator, this becomes:

```
boolean condition ? execute true code : execute false code
```

When using a variable with the following expression:

```
$F{column_value}.intValue() == 42 ? "Life, Universe, Everything" : "Naught"
```

Then the variable's value would be "Life, Universe, Everything" if, and only if, the integer value of `$F{column_value}` is equal to 42.

Where things get a little obtuse is when you have to have nested conditions. For these, put the nested conditions in parenthesis and on a separate line:

```
condition1 ?
  (condition2 ? true_code2 : false_code2) :
  false_code1
```

So when you need to do many of them:

```
condition1 ?
  (condition2 ?
    (condition3 ? true_code3 : false_code3) :
    false_code2) :
  (condition4 ? true_code4 : false_code4)
```

Answer (score 24):

example of expression in ireport:

```
(
    $F{foo} == 0 ?
    "Planned" :
    $F{foo} == 1 ?
    "Reserved" :
    $F{foo} == 2 ?
    "Canceled" :
    $F{foo} == 3 ?
    "Absent" :
    $F{foo} == 4 ?
    "Complete" :
    "Unknown"
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use if-else condition:

1. if customer name is null write '-' (absent), else write customer name.

Be careful of your field data type!

```xml
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
  <![CDATA[
    $F{CustomerName} == null ? '-' : $F{CustomerName}
  ]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```