# How to change variable value on demand in JasperReports

Tags: variables, parameters, jasper-reports, ireport

I am working with *iReport*. Here is the situation:

I have some parameters named `branchID, spType`.

I have created one variable named `branchName (string)`  which is by default null.

What I need to do is, to change/ edit the value of the variable `branchName` depending on the values of `branchID` and `spType`

How can I do this with *JasperReports* using If Else. Is it something with the properties of the variable `branchName`? Any help/ Suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Expressions Scripting Language in Jasper reports is your friend!

What i can fathom from your query is that you want to compute the value of a variable based on values of two parameters. In short, you want to do something like:-

## Simple if-else

```
If (branchId == 1 && spType == "abc") 
     branchName = "Xyz1";
 else 
     branchName = "Xyz2";
```

In Jasper scripting language, the above expression can be written as :-

```
($P{branchId}==1 && 
 $P{spType} != null &&
 $P{spType}.equals("abc"))?"Xyz1":"Xyz2"
```

## Nested If-else

```
If (branchId == 1 && spType == "abc") 
    branchName = "Xyz1";
 else if (branchId = 2 && spType == "def")
    branchName = "Xyz2"; 
 else 
    branchName = "Xyz3";
```

Jasper expression:

```
( $P{branchId} ==1 &&
  $P{spType} !=null && 
  $P{spType}.equals("abc") ) ? "Xyz1" :
    (($P{branchId} == 2 &&
      $P{spType} != null &&
      $P{spType}.equals("def")) ? "Xyz2" : "Xyz3");
```

For more details, have a look at this tutorial: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_expression.htm

Here is a similar stackoverflow question also:
[doing comparison if else in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437323/doing-comparison-if-else-in-ireport)

For core concept, Page no. 10 of this pdf:
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

iReport support scripting using [expressions](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-expressions-using-groovy).

You can right click on a report element and click edit expression to open the expression editor.

Some useful notes in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437323/doing-comparison-if-else-in-ireport) as well.