# if statement with more conditions

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm creating a automatic report generator, it's getting all its information out of a database.

You can see the progress in the pdf, in that progress you have an specific status, which is always 0, 1, 2 or 3.

If the status is 0-1 it should change an image to an incomplete image.
If the status is 2 it should change the image to an complete image
and if the status is 3 it should change the image to an not attempted imaged.

I've a code that support the first 2 which is:

```
IF( $F{status} == 2) ? $P{IMG_DIR} + "scorm_completed.png" : $P{IMG_DIR} + "scorm_incomplete.png"
```

Is there anybody who knows what I have to change?

Comment: `IF( $F{status} == 2) ? $P{IMG_DIR} + "scorm_completed.png" : IF( $F{status} == 1) ? $P{IMG_DIR} + "scorm_incomplete.png" :  $P{IMG_DIR} + "other.png"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doing comparison if else in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437323/doing-comparison-if-else-in-jasperreports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you would go about doing this:

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="100" height="37"/>
    <imageExpression>
        <![CDATA[($F{status} == 3) ?
            $P{IMG_DIR} + "not_attempted.png" :
            (($F{status} == 2) ?
            $P{IMG_DIR} + "scorm_completed.png" :
            (($F{status} == 1 || $F{status} == 0) ?
            $P{IMG_DIR} + "scorm_incompleted.png" : null))]]>
    </imageExpression>
</image>
```

I am using a `null` placeholder for the case where the status is neither 0, 1, 2, or 3, but you might want to replace this with an error image.