# Jasper report : error with IF expression

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to append "%" to a textfield conditionally, but I am getting this error :

1. The method IF(boolean, String, String) is undefined for the type

   SuiviExercice_1441008823562_230431
                   value = IF(((java.lang.String)field_libelle.getValue()).equals(""),String.valueOf(((java.lang.Double)field_octoberData.getValue()))+"%",String.valueOf(((java.lang.Double)field_octoberData.getValue())));
   <>

Does anyone know why?

Comment: `IF` statement cannot have 3 parameters. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doing comparison if else in iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437323/doing-comparison-if-else-in-ireport)

Comment: ths same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247300/jasper-report-if-condition-in-text-field-value

Answer (score 3):

What about using ternary operations?

some_condition **?** condition_was_true **:** condition_was_false

in your case:

your_condition **?** your_text + "%" **:** your_text