# Jasper if condition

Tags: if-statement, jasper-reports, conditional-statements

I have a BigDecimal variable that contains number with minus(-) and not. I want to put static text that should be match with this conditions:

- If $V{saldo} contains minus (-) value The static text will show "Rugi"
- If $V {saldo} doesnt's contain minus(-) value the static text will show "Laba"

For example, if `$V{saldo} = -250000` then the static text should be `"Rugi"`, and if `$V{saldo} = 400000` then the static text should be "Laba"

Comment: Please review the answers given below, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doing comparison if else in iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437323/doing-comparison-if-else-in-ireport)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this if-else construct:

```
$V{saldo}.intValue() < 0 ? "Rugi" : "Laba"
```

Please see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437323/doing-comparison-if-else-in-ireport) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

First Check for ZERO then apply your logic

`$V{saldo}.$V{saldo} != 0.0 ? ($V{saldo}.intValue() < 0 ? "Rugi" : "Laba"): "Zero"`